# functionname.customfunction() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

So I am currently making a project and I want to do something like this:

```
functionname.customfunction();
```

I have seen it in other JavaScript libraries, and I want to know how to make it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You're going to have to explain *why* you want to do this and what it's intended to achieve. What is the problem you're trying to solve? In what way do you think this construct would help? What have you read about or tried so far?

Comment: Functions are objects, so just assign a function expression to the `functionname` like you would to any object and it should work

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to make a JavaScript library, and i'm trying to do a function called `speed.launch() `. I tried making a variable named speed, but it didn't work. I tried this: `var speed={};`. And it didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did *anything* happen? Was there an error? Did your computer explode? How is anybody supposed to help; we're not mind-readers.

Comment: ```var speed={};``` then ```speed.launch = function(){...}``` . This is not the best way to do this, but it should work.

Comment: @Pointy I know how to do it now, but anyways, the error said "speed.launch is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by initializing static method inside a class or object.

```
class functionname {
      static customfunction() {}
}
```

Now you ca call it like this

```
functionname.customefunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

the "functionname" should be an object and the "customfunction" should be a method of the object, you can take the course at [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/) and learn more about it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: Read this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), is gonna help you.